# Issue using cursor.execute and cursor.fetchall in python using sqlite

Tags: python, sql, database, eclipse, sqlite

I am having issues returning a list of all comments as tuples in my code. Here is what I have:

```
def list_comments(db, limit=None):
    """return a list of all comments as tuples

       - tuples are (id, useremail, page, comment)
       if limit is provided it should be an integer and only that
       many comments will be returned
    """

    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM comments")
    manyresults = cursor.fetchall()

    for row in cursor:
        return row
```

So what i'm trying to do is select everything from my comments table and return it:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
        id integer unique primary key autoincrement,
        useremail text,
        page text,
        comment text,
        FOREIGN KEY(useremail) REFERENCES users(email)
);"""
```

I am very new to this all so if I'm completely wrong please let me know where or what I'm doing wrong. Thanks!

EDIT: Here is a test I am running it against

```
 def test_list_comments(self):
    """The list_comments procedure should return a list of tuples
    one for each of the comment entries in the database, each tuple
    should contain """

    clist = interface.list_comments(self.db)

    # we should have the same number of comments as we created
    self.assertEquals(len(clist), len(self.comments), "Wrong number of comments returned from list_units, expected %d, got %d" % (len(self.comments), len(clist)))

    # comments should be in order so the largest id should be first
    self.assertEquals(clist[0][0], self.comments[-1][0], "Wrong comment id first in comment list, expected %d, got %d" % (clist[0][0], self.comments[-1][0]))

    # and the comment list should be ordered by id
    ids = [c[0] for c in clist]
    self.assertEqual(sorted(ids, reverse=True), ids, "List of comments returned is not in large-to-small order: %s" % (ids,))

    # try the limit argument
    clist = interface.list_comments(self.db, 3)
    self.assertEquals(len(clist), 3, "Wrong number of comments returned from list_comments with a limit argument, expected 3, got %d" % (len(clist),))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple issues:

1. You are not doing anything with the result of `cursor.fetchall()`
2. You are only returning the first result, not all of them

I think what you need is:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM comments")
manyresults = cursor.fetchall()
return list(manyresults)
```

Though you can also do:

```
return list(cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM comments"))
```

Comment: Oh that makes lots more sense I don't know why I didn't see that before. I do still somehow get an exception error using the tests I added to the original question description..

Comment: self.assertEquals(clist[0][0], self.comments[-1][0], "Wrong comment id first in comment list, expected %d, got %d" % (clist[0][0], self.comments[-1][0]))
AssertionError: Wrong comment id first in comment list, expected 0, got 11

Comment: You need to add 'ORDER BY id' to query otherwise the result will not be ordered by anything.

Comment: Still doesn't change that the test got 11 when 0 was expected. Thanks for the help so far I appreciate it!

Comment: If you are doing an 'order by' the largest id will be last. You need 'order by id desc' to have the largest id first.

Comment: I actually already made sure I had is DESC but instead i'm no longer passing the first test


self.assertEquals(len(clist), 3, "Wrong number of comments returned from list_comments with a limit argument, expected 3, got %d" % (len(clist),))
AssertionError: Wrong number of comments returned from list_comments with a limit argument, expected 3, got 12